# How to SaveAs pdf?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Trying to save to pdf.

```
Sub fill2()
    TemplateName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\DOC\test.docx"
    PdfPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\OutPut"
    sSaveFolder = PdfPath & "\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd" & ".pdf")

    Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WD = WA.Documents.Add(TemplateName)
    WA.Visible = False

    WD.SaveAs sSaveFolder, 17
    WD.Close False: Set WD = Nothing
    WA.Quit False: Set WA = Nothing
End Sub
```

The file saves with the extension p2f rather than pdf (changing letter d to number 2).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking Excel to format your filename like so:

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd" & ".pdf")
```

which is, to Excel, exactly the same as:

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd.pdf")
```

Because `.pdf` contains a `d`, it is replacing it with the day number (2).

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd.pdf")
                       ^^  ^
```

Rearrange your formatting element to just the `yyyy.mm.dd` and then add on your file extension separately:

```
sSaveFolder = PdfPath & "\" & Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a parenthesis in the wrong spot.  Try this:

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy.mm.dd") & ".pdf"
```